Packer image build failed with Bitbucket pipeline
<@&1272907579135230054>  <@&1272907753920401420>  <@&1272907828742459412>
Issue Summary
I want to create an AMI with a docker image. I tried to develop using the Bitbucket pipeline. I am getting a pipeline failure, due to an ssh issue. Do you have any idea where to store my SSH keys? I am building an an image with Ansible to execute Packer. If you need any more details, please let me know.
Steps to reproduce: I am getting the access key and secret key from aws ssm parameter store.
Expected result: To get ami with datadog agent
Actual Results: Pipeline failed. Says "amazon-ebs.this: Timeout waiting for SSH"
Error details:
Build 'amazon-ebs.this' errored after 7 minutes 8 seconds: Timeout waiting for SSH.

The SSH error for packer, can be issued because many reasons, not just because of the ssh key which make it harder to tell you the solution, in this discussion you can find some solutions if nothing worked out, you can write your full packer configuration and how are you trying to launch (the AWS instance configuration, networking..).
Having problems with Packer: amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for SSH
you can add export PACKER_LOG=1 so you can see some detailed logs which can bring you closer to the issue.

The issue got resolve for as I am changed public ip association from false to true. associate_public_ip_address = true
